# how to bypass "child process exited abnormally"

Tags: shell, tcl

I was trying to execute the following 2 lines as Tcl scripts.
As keyword1 sometimes doesn't exist in file1, grep returns status code 1, which exec treats as error and stops execute the second line. How do I force it run both lines no matter there is a match or not.

```
exec grep keyword_1 file_1 > report_1
exec grep keyword_2 file_2 > report_2
```

Comment: See http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec and scroll down to the "Child Status" section. Essentially, `exec` handles non-zero exit statuses as errors, and `grep` returns "1" when the pattern is not found.

Comment: Thank you, yes I've read that article but I don't see how it use catch to ignore this error code.

Answer (score 3):

You can catch the exceptions using `catch` command.

```
if {[catch {exec grep keyword_1 file_1 > report_1} result]} {
    puts "problem in executing grep on file1"
    puts "Reason : $result"
}
if {[catch {exec grep keyword_2 file_2 > report_2} result]} {
    puts "problem in executing grep on file2"
    puts "Reason : $result"
}
```

If you dont care status of the command which you are executing or the error messages, then it can be written simply as,

```
catch {exec grep keyword_1 file_1 > report_1}
catch {exec grep keyword_2 file_2 > report_2}
```

**Reference :** [catch](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/catch.htm)

Comment: Also consider whether the search would be better done directly in Tcl. Many uses of grep in the wild are pure overkill.

Comment: @Dinesh Catch {...} works just fine, it is what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You could ignore grep's exit status like this:

```
exec sh -c {grep keyword_1 file_1 > report_1; true}
exec sh -c {grep keyword_2 file_2 > report_2; true}
```

but, probably better to use `catch` as @Dinesh suggests

Or use `try` if you have a modern Tcl

```
try {exec grep keyword_1 file_1 > report_1} trap CHILDSTATUS {} {}
try {exec grep keyword_2 file_2 > report_2} trap CHILDSTATUS {} {}
```